# How can I send a slider value over Bluetooth LE every time the slider changes without spamming "Transaction already in progress" errors?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm controlling the speed of a motor over BLE with a GUI in a website. Every time the slider changes position a new "oninput" event is triggered. This happens about 50x /sec when you're using the slider. Because you can only send one BLE transmission at a time and a BLE transmission takes ~50ms there are a lot of "A transaction is already in progress errors". This results in the last few inputs being lost. When you quickly flick the slider from left to right the stepper motor will receive that the position is somewhere in the middle. I want a solution where:

- I can change the slider and see the stepper motor speed up and slow down before I release the slider.
- I also want the final value before I stop sliding to be the one that the stepper motor eventually settles on.

Here's my hacky solution: On input an asynchronous method is called that tries to send the value. If it fails then it checks if it failed because there was already another transmission in progress and not some other error. If that's the case it then checks if the value it was trying to send is still the most recent value after failing to send. Only if those 2 conditions are met it will call itself and try again.

Here's the code:

```
document.getElementById("sldSpeed").oninput = updateSpeed;
let speed = 0;
function updateSpeed() {
    speed = document.getElementById("sldSpeed").value;
    speed = parseInt(speed * 100);
    document.getElementById("lblSpeed").innerHTML = `${speed / 100} cm/s`;
    schrijfRealTimeSpeed(speed);
};

async function schrijfRealTimeSpeed(waarde) {
    schrijfUint32Value(karDelta, waarde)
        .catch((problem) => {
            if (problem.message === "GATT operation already in progress." & waarde === speed)
                schrijfRealTimeSpeed(waarde);
        });
}
```

(this schrijfUint32Value(karDelta, waarde) calles a methode in a BLE module script and converts the number to a byte array and then
uses the Javascript BLE function karakteristiek.writeValueWithResponse(byteArr) )

Question: I'm abusing the error system and this probably isn't efficiënt. The authors on git said that the correct way is to only send a new request once the previous request has returned a promise so you don't get the "GAAT transmission in progress" errors in the first place. Knowing this, is there a cleaner more efficiënt, better and more javascript-like way to solve this?

Comment: You can use JS Promise mechanism to achieve this. Probably save the slider value changes in an array and when promise is fulfilled, send the next value.

Comment: @Ismail now that I think about it I suspect the array only needs to be 1 long? Because as soon as you have a more recent value all the old ones don't matter. At any given moment only the value being send and the most recent value in the queue matter no? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you seem to have a clear picture of this. In that case, simply update a variable with the latest position on slider. As soon as promise is fulfilled, your next value which will get passed on will be most recent change.

Comment: It looks like you already are saving your latest change in [var speed]. I assume you have an event listener which runs the function updatespeed?

Comment: @Ismail yes I'll add that method too to make it more clear

Comment: @Ismail I think I know what I want I just don't know how to do it properly. Could you give me some code? How do I make sure that after the promise is fulfilled only the most recent number will be waiting to take the next turn?

Comment: I added answer, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you

```
document.getElementById("sldSpeed").oninput = updateSpeed;
let speed = 0;
let firstrun = true;
let lastvalue = 0;
function updateSpeed() {
speed = document.getElementById("sldSpeed").value;
speed = parseInt(speed * 100);
document.getElementById("lblSpeed").innerHTML = `${speed / 100}cm/s`;
  if (firstrun == true)
  {
    firstrun = false;
    schrijfRealTimeSpeed(speed);
  }

}
async function schrijfRealTimeSpeed(waarde) {

   const realtimepromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   if (lastvalue!= waarde)
{
 lastvalue = waarde;
await schrijfUint32Value(karDelta, waarde);
resolve();
  } else
  {
  reject();
  firstrun = true;
    }
      });
  
   realtimepromise.then( (val) => schrijfRealTimeSpeed(speed));

   }
```

Comment: I updated the code and added async in promise function

Comment: I'm not sure how the "firstrun" variable ever gets sent back to true?

Comment: You can add listener for stop or released? and in that handler set it back to true.

Comment: You can also declare variable for lastvaluesent and check if lastvaluesent is equal to current value? then do not call function and reject instead of resolve.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't there be at maximum be only 2 values sent? One during movement and one when movement stops?

Comment: I updated the code. Everytime slider changes it's value it will update the value. If your slider is set up to only step two values then it will be 2.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your code. If the promise is rejected the last statement in the function schrijfRealTimeSpeed won't be executed, correct?

Comment: That should only run if promise is resolved.

Comment: I think I get it. I implemented it and it works but I was able to reduce the amount of code. Should I post another answer to ask if it's still what you had in mind? I also think that if the connection drops out when using your method that you will get an infinete loop but taht's a minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

With Ignamuses solution I was able to write a version that worked for my application. I removed some promises and added a check for network errors to prevent an infinite loop:

```
let speed = 0;
let busy = false;
let speedLastTransmitted = 0;

document.getElementById("sldSpeed").oninput = updateSpeed;

function updateSpeed() {
    speed = document.getElementById("sldSpeed").value;
    speed = parseInt(speed * 100);
    document.getElementById("lblSpeed").innerHTML = `${speed / 100}cm/s`;
    if (busy === false) {
        busy = true;
        schrijfRealTimeSpeed(speed);
    }
}
async function schrijfRealTimeSpeed(waarde) {
    if (speedLastTransmitted === waarde)
        busy = false;
    else {
        schrijfUint32Value(karDelta, waarde)
            .then(() => {
                speedLastTransmitted = waarde;
                schrijfRealTimeSpeed(speed);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ismail I rewrote your solution somewhat because It didn't work fully after pasting it and I couldn't figure out how it worked. I think this is what you meant right?